# Efficient way of parsing multiple large csv files using CSVParser

Tags: java

I am iterating through all 30 large files, parse each using CSVParser, and convert each line to some object.  I use java 8's parallel stream to hopefully be able to load them in parallel.  But I am getting Java heap space error.  I tried increasing the memory to -Xmx1024m but still got the heap space error.  How should I be doing the loading of these files efficiently?

Comment: What are you going to do with all those line? You should stream into and do the stuff rather than buffering it.

Comment: Include your processing into the stream, so you won't ever require more than one row per file to be present in the heap. For more information we probably need more details about what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting to load too much information into memory.  Either way you do it (in parallel, or one file at a time), you will run out of memory if you want to hold too many objects in memory at the same time.

This is not an "efficiency" problem.  It is a more fundamental problem with the design of your application.  Ask yourself why you need to hold all of those object in memory at the same time, and whether you can either avoid that or reduce the space needed to represent the information you need.